# Java file writer

Tags: java

I have been given this task:

Write a program that takes as input a number n and a text string filename and writes n lines to the file where each line is of the form: i: sqrt(i) sqrt(i) sqrt(i). The first column ranges from 1..n whilst the first square root is to one decimal place, the second is to two decimal places and the third is to three decimal places.

And I came up with this code with help from one of my college tutors but..

```
  public static void writeFile(final String filePath, final int n) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath))) {
        final String format = "%-10s %-10.1f %-10.2f %-10.3f %n";
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            final double root = Math.sqrt(i);
            writer.write(String.format(format,i+":",root ,root,root));
        }
    }
}
```

.... how would I include the text file that's meant to be used? I thought I'd do something similar to filepath = file.txt. for example. But I'm not sure how to incorporate that in the code. I came up with formatting it to the decimal places like the task asks. Would I need to include it in the for loop or outside the loop? Thanks

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calling method should be passing in the file name as a part of the filePath variable.
If the filePath in the parameter doesnt have a file name, then you can define the file name inside the method and concatenate with the input filePath. You can use the derived file path to create your file writer object.

```
String completeFilePath = filePath.concat("file.txt");

try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(completeFilePath))) {
...
}
```

Also please flush/close the writer object once you are done with the operation.

Comment: Flush is called automatically on close, close is automatically on leaving linkage because of the interface `AutoClosable`.

Comment: thank you. So would I need to add the entire directory like: ("c:/documents/file.txt") or just add the file

Comment: It depends... If the file is in a different location outside of your workspace folder, u need to give the full path. I would advise, to always use the full path, instead of just the file name

Answer (score 0):

When you call your method you will pass the filePath as an argument. You only need to set in once in your code

`writeFile("textfile.txt",5);`